# Heroku Is giving me 'error h14 for my django project

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

When I go to my heroku project it says to run `heroku logs --tail`, and when I do that I get:

```
2022-01-16T04:52:26.342707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=584f14b8-99da-4cfc-bfad-1811755db6fb fwd="49.149.136.159" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-16T04:52:27.375325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myproject.herokuapp.com request_id=63993a67-e160-4762-a520-9164646b74f7 fwd="49.149.136.159" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I've tried `heroku ps:scale web=1` but I get:

```
Scaling web processes... failed
 !    No such type as web
```

This is my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -
```

How do I get my site working?

Comment: Give this a try ```web: gunicorn riseupontario.wsgi:application --log-file -```

Comment: @sumithran still not working... argh!

Answer (score 0):

Got it... my procfile was named 'procfile' not 'Procfile', plus it was in my gitignore.